# devise confirmable with React

Tags: reactjs, ruby-on-rails, devise, devise-confirmable

There is a problem I couldn't find an answer for on the internet.
I am trying to make an app with react and ruby.

I am using devise in order to authenticate my users and I would like to use the confirmable attribute and here is my problem:
The confirmation link send by devise point to the route "auth/confirm?confirmation_token=XXX', but it is also the route used by devise to confirm the mail. I tried to add a react page at this route, but i receive this error:
[image: error when clicking on the link in the mail.]

here is my index.jsx file:

```
<Router>
  <Navbar />
  <Routes>
    <Route path="/" element={<Home />} />
    <Route path="/registration" element={<UserRegistration />} />
    <Route path="/login" element={<UserLogin />} />
    <Route path="/registration/confirmation" element={<ConfirmRegistration />} />
    <Route path="/auth/confirm" element={<MailConfirmation />} />
  </Routes>
</Router>
```

So, do I have to change the link in the mail in order to point to a react component and then confirm with a call to the corresponding devise route?
Or is there another way of doing it more cleverly?